# How to bridge an wlan to lan on raspberry pi?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, bridge

A have the IP-camera connected to ethernet interface, and the wi-fi network. How can i access the camera from any device in wi-fi network (see scheme 1)?

```
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0 wlan0
```

And get the following error:

```
can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported
```

[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTBpb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`brctl addif` can only add one interface at a time according to man page. Try:

```
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
sudo brctl addif br0 wlan0
```

Comment: same error `can't add wlan0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported`

Comment: Interesting. I regularly bridge WiFi interfaces with ethernet on my openwrt access points without problems. Is dmesg showing anything related (like complaining that wlan0 driver is not supporting bridging)?